# Why can't I find edittext and textview inside the dialog box

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, dialog

I have tried to put edittext inside a dialog box. On execution only the button is being displayed, but not the edittext and textview, which I defined in the xml. I am a beginner can someone help me with this.

```
nametv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchDistibutorProduct.this);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View customlayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.update,null);
        builder.setView(customlayout);

        /*builder.create();
        builder.show();*/
        //  builder.setCancelable(false);
        //  builder.setTitle("UPdate values");

        final TextView textView =  customlayout.findViewById(R.id.updatetv);
        final EditText editText = customlayout.findViewById(R.id.updateet);

        Button button =customlayout.findViewById(R.id.updatebtn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                textView.setText(workerlist.get(0).getName());
                final String nameupdate = editText.getText().toString();

                String name= workerlist.get(0).getName();
                String id= workerlist.get(0).getId();
                if(!name.equals( nameupdate) ) {
                    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                    hashMap.put("name", nameupdate);
                    databaseworker = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Patient");

                    databaseworker.child(id).updateChildren(hashMap);
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                } 
                else {
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    Toast.makeText(SearchDistibutorProduct.this, "no change is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
       });

    builder.create();
    builder.show();

    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share xml code

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in the XML file, try with this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updatetv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/updateet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updatebtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```